# javascript offsetTop return 0 the first time but return the good value after

Tags: javascript, datatables

I'm using the datatable plugin on my website and I make a 'Add button' to add a new row to the table. When the row is added, I scroll to the row. Actually I managed to do it because I did it a different way but I want to understand where the bug was

```
    var myTable = $('#id_Table').DataTable({
        "bSort" : false
    });

    var emptyArrayOfGAElement = makeEmptyArray(myTable.columns().nodes().length);


    $("#btnAddRow").click(function(){

        // At the beginning I wanted to use the offsetTop property of the row added
        var trst = myTable.row.add(emptyArrayOfGAElement).draw(false).node();
        console.log($(trst));
        console.log($(trst)[0].offsetTop);
        console.log('----------------');


        /* This doesn't work for the first row added because it returned 0
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop : $(trst)[0].offsetTop
        }, 500);
        */


        // This work 
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop : $('#id_Table').offset().top
        }, 500);

        myTable.page('last').draw('page');
    });
```

At the beginning I wanted to use the offsetTop property of the row added, but for the first row added '$(trst)[0].offsetTop' returned 0 value instead of when I looked at the console log the offsetTop property is not equal to 0

[image: console]

That's my codepen.io : http://codepen.io/robert91/pen/aNKBOv

Thanks

Comment: Not a bug. I'm 99% sure of asynchronous problem. Show the working example, but if it's asynchronous problem you need to wait to finish the first operation (show row) to execute second operation (calculate offset).

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude Thanks for your reply, this is my working example I commented the 'bug', but I've also thought that is an asynchronous problem but I wasn't sure because when I re-add a row this work

Comment: That's not a working example. That's a piece of code. A working example means that the piece of code works, it's runnable and reproduces the issue. See stacksnippets or external services like jsfiddle.net. Read more: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask || **http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve**

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude oups sorry, I'll make that

Comment: No problem, none of us was born learned.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude I did it

Comment: I hate codepen, it's mandatory to register to save (fork) a modification and share with you. However, it works for me. If I remove the comment in the line you said that doesn't work, it works for me (¿?). It throws me the values `38` for first row addition and `90` for the second row addition. It works everytime.

Comment: It seems to work on codepen but on my website it doesn't work, it's strange ...

Comment: Hummmmm. Are you trying to debug your own code in your project? It means, set breakpoints in the click event and go step by step to see why it doesn't work. Maybe you need a tutorial. Firefox: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger Chrome: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging